# How to determine flash size of NodeMCU?

Tags: nodemcu

Just bought a couple of NodeMCU from vendor on AliExpress. They were advertised as "v2" and having 4M flash.

How can I verify the flash size? The board says "Ver 0.1", but don't know if that means anything.

Comment: "NodeMCU" as a term normally refers to the NodeMCU firmware. Do you mean you bought the NodeMCU devkits V2/1.0? See [my comparison](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/) if you're not sure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have basically two options: install a firmware (NodeMCU, Arduino, etc.) and use their functions or extract the flash ID and look it up.

**Install NodeMCU**

- [Build](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/) and [flash](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/) the NodeMCU firmware.
- Run `print(node.flashsize())`

**Chip ID**

- install [esptool.py](https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool)
- run `esptool.py -p <serial-port> flash_id` (gives you a hex manufacturer & chip ID)
- look up the chip in https://review.coreboot.org/plugins/gitiles/flashrom/+/refs/heads/master/include/flashchips.h

Comment: Before flashing you need to know flash memory size, so this is not an option.

Comment: @jumpjack that's why I gave two options, one works w/o flashing a firmware. I don't understand your comment. Besides, esptool.py can auto-detect flash size since v1.2. So, you don't have to know the flash size to install the firmware.

Comment: The Chip ID method outputs the size of the flash too without having to look up the chip specs:  e.g. Detected flash size: 4MB

Comment: @EdPlese, that's correct, recent versions of esptool.py (2.x) do that.

Comment: The link to coreboot is broken @MarcelStör

Answer (score 3):

As Marcel Stor said before in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633139/4511648), the [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) may be used to find the flash size.

- Just run `python esptool.py -p <serial_port> flash_id`
- Flash size is output like this `Detected flash size: xx`

Output sample

[image]